# The instance ID does not exist even when I clearly see it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm unsure why boto3 can't find my EC2 instance.

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
instance = conn.get_all_instances(["i-0d8d1c65cba1e9066"])[0].instances[0]
```

Is giving me the error:

```
The instance ID 'i-0d8d1c65cba1e9066' does not exist
```

In AWS:
[image]

Comment: Did you verify that the credentials you're using for the boto client is for the account you're looking at?

Comment: Adding to @Brian comment, make sure the credentials has access to fetch instance information.

Comment: You mentioned boto3 but your code appears to be using boto. The boto library was deprecated some time ago. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the old boto library. You need to use boto3 version.

```
py -m pip install boto3 # to install boto3 on your machine
```

Here is the snippet.

```
import boto3
ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2", region_name="us-east-1")
response = ec2_client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=["i-0d8d1c65cba1e9066"])
print(response)
```

Hope this helps. Mark it as answered after testing.

Comment: This did not solve my issue

Comment: Typical reasons for this not returning the expected results are all user error: either using AWS credentials for the wrong account or targeting the wrong AWS region. Does `ec2_client.describe_instances()` retrieve the expected EC2 results?